# sample jquery library is not working

Tags: input

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

when I add this library to my web project my `persianDatepicker` is working without this not working.

when I add another jquery library is same not working

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $("#spenddate").persianDatepicker();
 });
</script>

Comment: suppose i have a input tag <input id=""spenddate" type="text"> when i am adding the id of the mentioned input tag,with having of this jquery library ("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js") it is working, but when i want to add jquery library which is not connected directly to internet on that time it is not working,please guide us.

Comment: Take a look at these links: https://github.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker and https://github.com/babakhani/pwt.datepicker I don't know which one you are using but they clearly wrote there what dependencies they have.

Comment: I'm saying again, add all the code, not just part of it.

Comment: Dear i am using this plugin from this site (https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/persian/)